# Trying to use rails: Load Error (no such file...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just installed rails and am working my way through the tutorial on railstutorial.org. In CH2 where you set up the basic app, after I generate the scaffold for the users and I try to load the page, @http@://localhost:3000/users  I receive:

> LoadError: (no such file to load -- openssl):

The default page loads properly. I even tried the tutorial on http://guides.rubyonrails.org and changed the `config/routes.rb` file to read:

```
  Blog::Application.routes.draw do    
  #...  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"  
  # just remember to delete          public/index.html.  
  root :to => "home#index"
```

The error is still the same. I am not sure what openssl is.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Edit: Sorry. Using Fedora 13 and Ruby1.9.2/Rails 3.0

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Also mention the version of Ruby & Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RVM, you can manage ruby versions and gems easily. It also provides answers for many questions related to missing libraries like openssl in your case. [link text](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Ruby was built without OpenSSL support. Try building from source, following step 4 of the [readme](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/README?view=markup): edit ext/Setup and remove the # before openssl. Then `make` and `make install`.

Note: I don't have a Fedora system available, so I haven't tested this.

Comment: Changed the file as instructed and ran make-make install. Same result. I probably messed up something. Thanks though

Comment: If you don't have the ssl headers, it won't build. Did you get any output along those lines when you ran make?